# How to compare in Matlab two matrices of different dimension and get the frequency of equal rows?

Tags: matlab, matrix, comparison

I have matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `hxk` and a matrix `B` of dimension `yxk`. I want to construct a vector `C` of dimension `yx1` listing in each row `j` how many times `B(j,:)` appears in `A`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking for perfect matches, one solution with `bsxfun` -

```
C = squeeze(sum(all(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(B,[3 2 1])),2),1))
```

Comment: @Shai Can't agree more really and makes it a one-liner! :) Appreciate the +1!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist2.html) (from the Statistics Toolbox):

```
C = sum(pdist2(A, B)==0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `ismember` and `accumarray`

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 10 11 12; 7 8 9];
B=[1 2 3; 10 11 12; 3 4 5; 7 8 9];
[uB,aB,cB]=unique(B,'rows');
[~,LocB] = ismember(A,uB,'rows');
C = accumarray(nonzeros(LocB),1,[size(B,1),1]);
C=C(cB);
```

which returns

```
C =

 2     1     0     2
```

or some crazy coding which seems to be faster for most instances:

```
[u,v,w]=unique([B;A],'rows');
wB=w(1:size(B,1));
wA=w(size(B,1)+1:end);
C=accumarray(wA,1,[numel(v),1]);
C=C(wB);
```

Comment: So you had the same idea. :-)

Comment: Hm. I just did some comparison with random data and I didn't get the same results as Luis and Divakar twice. There might be a bug somewhere... I'm just checking!

Comment: Fails for non unique rows in B. I saw your incomplete and deleted answer to the other question, this "influenced" my thoughts ;)

Comment: :-) Just found the problem of duplicate entries in `B`.

Comment: Fixed it, should be `numel(v)`

Comment: @Daniel: You could use `numel(u)` to omit `v` entirely. (Which might help to make the code more understandable)

Comment: @knedlsepp: `numel(u)` is to large, might be replaced by `size(u,1)` which is identical to `numel(v)`

Comment: Oh yeah, `size(.,1)` of course! But one could either omit `u` or `v` entirely as we only need the number of unique rows.